KeyError: 'input_ids' arise when I used prompt-tuned Codet5 for
I successfully prompt tuned codet5, however, I can't use the fine-tuned model for inference.
It shows Key error 'input_ids':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/liangpeng/project/Mabel/detection/prompt_tuning/codet5_pilot.py", line 35, in <module>
    generated_ids = peft_model.generate(input_ids, max_length=2048)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/liangpeng/project/anaconda3/envs/linghao/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py", line 1192, in generate
    outputs = self.base_model.generate(**kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/liangpeng/project/anaconda3/envs/linghao/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/liangpeng/project/anaconda3/envs/linghao/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1527, in generate
    result = self._greedy_search(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/liangpeng/project/anaconda3/envs/linghao/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 2408, in _greedy_search
    model_inputs = self.prepare_inputs_for_generation(input_ids, **model_kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/liangpeng/project/anaconda3/envs/linghao/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py", line 1225, in prepare_inputs_for_generation
    size = model_kwargs["input_ids"].shape[0], peft_config.num_virtual_tokens
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'input_ids'

Here is the code I used the model for inference:
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
import torch

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

text_column = 'Input'

model_name_or_path = '/home/liangpeng/project/Mabel/CLMs/codet5_base_multi_sum_local'
tokenizer_name_or_path = '/home/liangpeng/project/Mabel/CLMs/codet5_base_multi_sum_local'
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_name_or_path)

content = '''Please read the following Java method code and analyze the code smell of method level, pointing out the reason:

    /** 
    * 事项移动到待办
    */
    @PostMapping("/waiting") public R<TaskRes> toWaiting(@RequestBody @Validated TaskUpdStatusReq req){
    baseService.toWaiting(req);
    return R.ok(baseService.listTask(req.getTodoId()));
    }
'''

def inference():
    def generate(inputs, infer_model):
        with torch.no_grad():
            inputs = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in inputs.items()}
            outputs = infer_model.generate(
                input_ids=inputs["input_ids"].to(device),
                attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"].to(device),
                max_new_tokens = 60,
                eos_token_id = 3
            )
            

    '''(1) base model_inference'''
    base_model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
    base_model.to(device)
    inputs = tokenizer(f'{text_column}: {content}\nLabel:',return_tensors='pt')
    generate(inputs, base_model)
    print('-----------------------------')

    '''(2) prompt tuning model_inference'''
    from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
    # peft_model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, model_id='/home/liangpeng/output/checkpoint-400')
    # peft_model = peft_model.to(device)
    # inputs = tokenizer(f'{text_column}: {content}\nLabel:', return_tensors='pt').to(device)
    
    # print(tokenizer.decode(peft_model.generate(input_ids=inputs["input_ids"], attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"], max_length=60, do_sample=True)[0], skip_special_tokens=True))

    path = '/home/liangpeng/output/checkpoint-400'
    config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(path)
    pretrained_model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
    prompt_tuned_model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model, path)
    prompt_tuned_model.to(device)
    
    inputs_p = tokenizer(f'{text_column}: {content}\nLabel:', return_tensors='pt')
    print(f'-----------------------------{inputs_p}')
    inputs_p = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in inputs_p.items()}
    print('input_ids' in inputs_p)
    print(tokenizer.decode(prompt_tuned_model.generate(input_ids=inputs_p['input_ids'].to(device), attention_mask=inputs_p['attention_mask'].to(device), max_length=60, do_sample=True)[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
    generate(inputs, prompt_tuned_model)

inference()

Actually, print(inputs_p.keys()) shows that inputs_p is a dict and has 'input_ids' and 'attention_mask'. I don't know why this error arose. Please help me, thank u
Please tell me how to address this error
